# In c# how do I count the number of words in each index of a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, count, split

For example I've got a text file that I've put into an array and then I have split that array by the full stops (so each sentence is in its own index of the new array) using the following:

```
textSplitArray = textArray[j].Split('.');
```

How would I then count the number of words in each index of textSplitArray to determine which sentence has the most words? Is it possible to do this or would I have to do it another way?

I've tried searching everywhere but can't seem to find an answer

Comment: What have you tried? This is a basic problem which can be solved using two for loops.

Comment: Do you have proper handling for common abbreviations like "e.g."?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for that. I'm fairly new to this and I wasn't sure about how to deal with the indexes of an array that has been created out of splitting another array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know which sentence is the longest (i.e. contains maximum words) use

```
var result = textSplitArray.OrderByDescending(x => x.Split(' ').Length)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

And if you want to know number of words in that longest sentence, use

```
int Max = textSplitArray.Max(x => x.Split(' ').Length);
```

OR

```
int Max = result.Length;
```

Since every two words in a sentence can be separated by space, that's why i have split each sentence based on `' '` space.

Comment: Right, and if you want to get the one: `var longestSentence = textSplitArray.OrderByDescending(x => x.Split(' ').Length).First();`. (in regards to asked `to determine which sentence has the most words`)

Comment: Eliminate double space before counting. (It is common in some countries to start a new sentence with 2 white spaces.)

Comment: @FilipDeVos: That comes under localization. Moreover OP has not given us any sample.

Comment: @FlipDeVos: Moreover, if there is any valid sentence there, and you just want the longest one, double white space should not matter :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] textSplitArray = textArray[j].Split('.');
        foreach (string s in textSplitArray)
        {
            int NumberOfWords = s.Split(' ').Length;                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use lambada expression like this :

```
 var max = textSplitArray.Select((s,i) =>
    {
        return new { value = s.Split(' ').Count() , index = i};
    }).OrderByDescending(item=>item.value).FirstOrDefault();
 int maxValue = max.value;
 int maxPos = max.index;


 //this will return anonymous object that has two properties : {index  , value} that refers to item's value and it's position in the sequence.
```

check if that help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] source = textSplitArray.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

`source.Length()` is your count.